# Close a Safari Tab

Tags: tabs, safari, applescript

I searched everywhere including here for a way to close a tab.
I have this code that should work:

```
tell application "Safari"
    repeat with aWindow in windows
        repeat with aTab in tabs of aWindow
            if name of aTab is "Facebook" then
                tell aTab to close
            end if
        end repeat
    end repeat
end tell
```

I have a Facebook tab open and it doesn't work, the code seemed to work when closing whole windows though…

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
tell application "Safari" to close (every tab of every window whose name = "Facebook")
```

You needed to include contents in the repeat loops of your code.

```
tell application "Safari"
    repeat with aWindow in windows
        repeat with aTab in tabs of (contents of aWindow)
            set aTab to contents of aTab
            if name of aTab is "Facebook" then
                tell aTab to close
            end if
        end repeat
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Your one did. My one produces a log that seems like everything works, but the tab remains open. Try running it.